# What regex pattern will get me separately all letters in an array from the below file?

Tags: java, regex

What regex pattern will get me separately all strings in an array from the below file?

```
Table_name_1 {
   Columns {
     Name : col_1
     Type: varchar(20)
     Description : to store stuff
   }
   Index {
     Name : Index1
     Column: col_1
   }
}
```

O/P:

```
[Table_name_1,Columns,Name:col_1 Type: varchar(20) Description : to store stuff,Index,Name : Index1 Column: col_1]
```

Comment: Do you want to get the alphabets using regex?

Comment: Pl share what you have tried?

Comment: Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\{)(?!\\s*\\{)[^{}]+");

This actually needs all strings to be extracted to be enclosed in curly braces.

Comment: Asked in 2016, edited in 2023.  "He's dead, Jim."